# Python3: why is -1 // 10 = -1?

Tags: python, python-3.x

1 // 10 == 0 with integer division so how come -1 // 10 != 0 ?

```
MPython 3.7.0b3 (v3.7.0b3:4e7efa9c6f, Mar 29 2018, 18:42:04) [MSC v.1913 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> -1 // 10
-1
```

Is this supposed to happen?

Comment: Basically, it floors the result of the plain division. This happens so that it coheres with the behavior of Python's `%` operator, which will give you a positive result when you take the modulus of a negative number. As an aside, please **always** use the generic [python] tag for all python related questions. This behavior is not specific to Python 3, and honestly Python 3 *is* Python. Python 2 is rapidly approaching it's end of life.

Comment: As for what I meant by "coheres", I meant that the following holds: `a = (a // b) * b + (a % b)`, check out the linked duplicate for more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is easier to explain like that:

operation `//` rounds "to the left" integer, i.e.

```
1//10 -> 0.1 -> 0
-1 //10 -> -0.1 -> -1 (as -1 on the X axis is to the left of -0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Floor division always rounds down.

```
1 / 10 = .1
```

which rounds down to 0.

```
-1 / 10 = -.1
```

which rounds down to - 1.